# Adding arbitrary text to graphael chart

Tags: javascript, svg, graphael

How would I go about adding a bit of text in the bottom left corner of a graphael chart area? I've googled, but the docs for raphael aren't very good :(

Cheers!
John.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your drawing placeholder defined as

```
var r = Raphael("holder");
```

so you place text on it like this

```
r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Donut Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
```

take a look at my jsfiddle

[g raphael js interactive donut](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/HzMVV/)